# relationship semaphores, mutexes, monitors, test-and-set and message passing

Tags: concurrency, operating-system, mutex, semaphore, monitor

I'm learning for an exam but the slides given by the professor aren't very helpful, and any searches I do give only muddy results. From what I could gather:

> **Semaphore:** counter with `down()` and `up()` operations that busy waits when calling `down(counter)` when `counter = 0` until `counter > 0` again
>
> **Mutex:** binary semaphore that can only be released by its owning process/thread
>
> **Test-and-set:** CPU instruction for retrieving a binary value and setting it to 1 *atomically*; used to implement mutexes
>
> **Monitor:** object that forces synchronized access, i.e. only one process/thread can access it at a time; can be implemented using
>   mutexes
>
> **Message passing:** processes send messages over some shared memory location to tell each other when the other can continue their work; this is effectively a semaphore that acts not only as a counter, but can also be used to exchange other data, i.e. some produce in the producer-consumer problem

**I have the following questions:**

1. Are these definitions correct?
2. Is there a way to implement monitors without mutexes?
3. Is there a way to implement mutexes without test-and-set, specifically without busy-waiting?
4. Are there uses for test-and-set other than to implement mutexes?

Comment: No, they are not correct.  What search suggested that a thread busy-waits on an empty semaphore?

Answer (score 0):

1. No.   You may or may not be able to implement them with busy waits, but that is by no means part of the definition.  The definition is Procure will return when the semaphore is available; Liberate will make the semaphore available. How they do that is up to them.  There is no other definition.
2. Yes.  Roughly speaking you can use any of { message passing, mutexes, semaphores } to implement { message passing, mutees, semaphores }.  By transitivity, anything you can implement with any of these, you can implement with any other of these.  But remember, you can kick a ball down a beach.   A ball is an object like a whale; thus you can kick a whale down a beach.  It might be a bit harder.
3. Yes.  Ask your favourite search-and-creep service about dekker and his fabulous algorithm.
4. Yes.  You might implement a multi-cpu state machine using test+set and test+clr, for example. Turing machines are fantastically flexible; simple abstractions like mutexes are meant to constrain that flexibility into something comprehensible.